# What's the difference between Apollo and Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to understand their difference.

From my understanding, Apollo is an implementation of GraphQL, and Gatsby is a framework that uses Apollo to build severside-rendered apps. Is that interpretation correct?

Would appreciate any input!

Answer (score 2):

**Apollo** (`apollo-client`) is a highly customizable graphql client with normalizing cache.

**Gatsby** is a node.js based static content generator. Resuls with a kind of [severside rendered] react app that can be 'run' from any (cheap) server supporting static content (static html, js, images) - even without any dynamic content support (f.e. php). Pages are prerendered as html (good for SEO) and transition between them is optimized (preloading).

**Gatsby and graphql** - it manages internally content in redux but provides graphql api data source consumed (in pages/templates) by own/internal client/lib to create static [fast] pages. This is **compile time only** 'server+client'. De facto not server and not client (not apollo), more like a set of helpers (customizable compiling system) using graphql querying format to describe templates data requirements, data processing etc.

You can use `apollo-client` [react] components/hooks in gatsby page templates for **run-time data fetching** [from static/generated pages]. You can use it in gatsby's node.js compiling environment for data fetching (instead of source plugins).